# Button not showing background 9 patch image

Tags: android

I am using a background 9 patch image name **button_normal.9.png**. The image is not showing as a background image of button. Got stuck for 5 hours still couldn't find it. Please help. Here are the respective files.

**This is button:**

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/s_id"
   android:text="@string/s_id_string"
   android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
   style="@style/MainScreen"/>
```

**Style MainScreen:**

```
<style name="MainScreen">
    <item name="android:layout_width">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_shape</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/button_text_color</item>
</style>
```

**button_shape file:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_normal"
    android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
    android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true"
      android:background="#ed2020"
      />
```

**button_text_color file:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ed2020"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ffffff"/>
```

**button_shape_pressed & button_shape_normal file is same:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="30dp" />
```

Comment: Nobody has a solution for this problem??

Answer (score 1):

try this **button_shape file**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:background="#ed2020" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_shape_normal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```